# Warning (code 1681): 'PASSWORD' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am getting the following warning when executing the following query:

```
SELECT password(%s);

Warning (code 1681): 'PASSWORD' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
```

How can I fix this? I am using Python / pymysql to execute queries.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=6409

Comment: To understand how to replace this, we need to understand what you're trying to do here exactly.

Comment: Ok, but How I can get password hash from decrypted password ? I need it for insert returned PASSWORD() result to mysql_users in proxysql.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't fix that easily. The warning message exactly tells what is going on: `SET PASSWORD` and the `PASSWORD(...)` function are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of MySQL; see the link @deceze gave in his comment.

So if you want your application to run with future versions of MySQL, don't use that syntax / function.

Eventually, MySQL or your Python database driver provides means to suppress certain warnings (I can't research this right now). But even if you manage to suppress that warning somehow, this will not keep the MySQL developers from removing `SET PASSWORD` and `PASSWORD(...)` from future versions.

A possible solution to the problem is to move the password hashing into the back-end application (i.e. into your PHP / Python / Perl / Whatever code). As an important bonus, this would enable you to use one of the modern hashing functions which are much harder to attack than the ones MySQL provides.